# Auto-Update Location in MapsActivity

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Attached to this post is my MapsActivity. Currently the location is read and updated upon clicking the icon in the top right (As Displayed in the image below).

How can I alter my code to allow the application to update location automatically as the user moves?

Ex: As I push a new location to the device, the marker will automatically move to the new location. As opposed to the current state in which the top right icon must be continuously pressed to update the location.

Thank you,

[Update Location Icon in Top Right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcC6C.png)

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Camera;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GoogleApiClient client;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private Location lastLocation;
    private Marker currentLocationMarker;
    public static final int REQUEST_LOCATION_CODE = 99;
    TextView textView;
    Geocoder geocoder;
    List<Address> addresses;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            checkLocationPermission();
        }

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
       switch(requestCode)
       {
           case REQUEST_LOCATION_CODE:
               if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
               {
                   //permission is granted
                   if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                       if(client == null){
                           buildGoogleApiClient();
                       }
                       mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                   }
               }
           else  {
                   Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   //Permission is denied
               }
               return;
       }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Click Icon in Top right for Current Location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mMap = googleMap;
        LatLng Phoenix = new LatLng(33.6056711, -112.4052378);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Phoenix).title("Default Location: Phoenix, AZ"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(Phoenix));


       if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        }
    }

        protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient(){
             client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

             client.connect();
        }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        lastLocation = location;

        if(currentLocationMarker != null){
            currentLocationMarker.remove();
        }

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Location");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));


        currentLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker((markerOptions));

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(10));

        if(client != null){
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(client, this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(client, locationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    public boolean checkLocationPermission(){
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
            {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION_CODE);
            }
            else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION_CODE);
            }
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }

    public void onZoom(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.zoomIn) {
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
        }
        if (view.getId() == R.id.zoomOut) {
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomOut());
        }
    }

    public void ChangeType(View view) {
        if (mMap.getMapType() == GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL) {
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Satellite Map Style", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        else if (mMap.getMapType() == GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE) {
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Hybrid Map Style", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if (mMap.getMapType() == GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID) {
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Terrain Map Style", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if (mMap.getMapType() == GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN) {
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Normal Map Style", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

Comment: In that example you have to move before there is a location update? I am also looking on implementing it into my preexisting code

Comment: Did you try to remove the line where you remove updates in onlocationchanged if(client != null){
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(client, this);
        }

Comment: When I remove this line, it does operate correctly. HOWEVER, it will not let me zoom out/move around the map correctly without automatically zooming back into user location

Comment: It is something to do with: "
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));"

How can I make this not disable the zoom in/zoom out function?

Comment: Maybe make a button to execute that code

Comment: The issue was in the delay of clicking "Send" in my emulator. 

Thank you for the help

For anyone looking for Zoom In/Out controls use the following:

Comment: public void onZoom(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.zoomIn) {
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
        }
        if (view.getId() == R.id.zoomOut) {
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomOut());
        }
    }